# selenium driver keep scrolling even after no scrolling exist

Tags: python, selenium

I want to scroll down to the end of a page, I tried this code:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r"C:\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)

scrolls = 200
for n in range(scrolls):
    try:
        print("scroll", n)
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)") # scroll to the bottom of the page:
        time.sleep(5)
    except:
        break
```

The code work fine and scroll down the page, but keep working (the loop keep working) even after the page stop scrolling (no more scrolling exist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to send the `END` button. Pressing it scrolls down immediately.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('html').send_keys(Keys.END)
```

Comment: return: NameError: name 'Keys' is not defined

Comment: @Ravanelli you have also to import `from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
` my bad, I thought that I put that in answer, sorry.

Comment: I did it but it performs only one scroll down

Comment: @Ravanelli so put it in a for loop `for i in range(50) driver.find_element_by_css_selector('html').send_keys(Keys.END)`

Comment: same thing, only one scroll

Comment: @Ravanelli can you send me an URL?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218215/discussion-between-ravanelli-and-aleksander-ikleiw).

Comment: I did it and started well but the driver stopped scrolling while the loop keep running !